# How to run a docker project through github code?

Tags: django, docker, github

I have a django web application code in github. From time to time, I make necessary updates and arrangements on the repository. I have to pull the project every time and make adjustments on the docker and run on my machine.

Is there a way to run docker synchronously with the code in my github repoitory? When I make a change in github I want the docker to pull it automatically and try to run the project without interrupting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hooks inside Jenkins we configure Git & Docker.

Say:
 When ever we push changes to git, then jenkins job will trigger, jenkins will pull the changes and build new docker image and push the image inside docker.